# Fulltext search in PostgreSQL with custom ranking based on different score for each keyword

Tags: sql, postgresql, search, full-text-search

Is there any way how to 'extend' `ts_rank` function in PostgreSQL or create custom `setweight`?

I have 2 tables, `records` and `tags`, `records` can have multiple tags. It is many to many association using table `records_tags`. `records_tags` has column `score` which means the same tag's score is different for each record and there is more levels than just 4 that are available as weights in PostgreSQL's setweight.

Simplified data example:

`records` table

```
 id |         title          |             description              | privacy
----+------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------
  1 | 'The best record ever' | 'Long and meaningful description...' |       1
  2 |       'Another record' | 'Description of the other record...' |       2
```

`tags` table

```
 id |           name
----+---------------------------
  1 | 'artificial intelligence'
  2 |        'machine learning'
  3 |            'life science'
```

`records_tags` table

```
 record_id | tag_id | score
-----------+--------+-------
         1 |      1 |    87
         1 |      2 |    23
         2 |      1 |    54
         2 |      2 |    67
         2 |      3 |    90
```

Data from these tables are merged in another table `search_documents` which has column `body` as type jsonb and includes aggregated tag names for each record.

The `search_documents.body` looks like this:

```
{
  title: 'The best record ever',
  description: 'Long and meaningful description...',
  tags: ['artificial intelligence', 'machine learning']
}
```

Right now I have implemented fulltext search using tsvector and setweight like this:

```
setweight(to_tsvector('simple', (body ->> 'tags')), 'A') || ' ' ||
setweight(to_tsvector('english', (body ->> 'title')), 'B') || ' ' ||
setweight(to_tsvector('english', (body ->> 'description')), 'C')
```

And search query like this:

```
SELECT
  ts_rank(sd.tsv, to_tsquery('english', ''' ' || :query || ' ''' || ':*'), 1) +
  ts_rank(sd.tsv, to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || :query || ' ''' || ':*'), 1) AS rank
  sd.id AS id
FROM
  search_documents sd
WHERE
  sd.tsv @@ to_tsquery('english', ''' ' || :query || ' ''' || ':*') OR
  sd.tsv @@ to_tsquery('simple', ''' ' || :query || ' ''' || ':*')
```

But it does not allow me to use the tag's score at all.

My idea is that I have a normalization function for the tag's score which returns the score in range from 0 to 1 and I use that to multiply the A weight. It would look something like this - `(x_i − min(x)) / (max(x) − min(x))`

Is there any way how I could use the tag's `score` in addition to current implementation while calculating the `rank`?

EDIT:

The `search_documents` is a table, not materialized view and has (or will have if something has to be added to make this work) all the data when the search process begins. It contains all items I want to search in and not just the `records` but others as well - `accounts` and `speakers`. When the source tables are updated so is the `search_documents`. There is also privacy column because each user has different rights and I do not want them to see the items in the search results when they cannot access them.

Example of the `search_documents` table:

```
 tsv | searchable_id | searchable_type | privacy | body
-----+---------------+-----------------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------
 ... |             1 |        'record' |       1 | { title: '...', description: '...', tags: ['...'] }
 ... |             1 |       'account' |       1 | { name: '...', description: '...' }
 ... |             1 |       'speaker' |       1 | { name: '...', description: '...' }
```

`tsv` is a ts_vector created with trigger on insert/update to the table. It is created like this:

```
IF NEW.searchable_type = 'record' THEN
  NEW.tsv := (
    setweight(to_tsvector('simple', (NEW.body ->> 'tags')), 'A') || ' ' ||
    setweight(to_tsvector('english', (NEW.body ->> 'title')), 'B') || ' ' ||
    setweight(to_tsvector('english', (NEW.body ->> 'description')), 'C')
  )::tsvector;
ELSE
  NEW.tsv := (
    setweight(to_tsvector('simple', (NEW.body ->> 'name')), 'A') || ' ' ||
    setweight(to_tsvector('english', (NEW.body ->> 'description')), 'C')
  )::tsvector;
END IF;
return NEW;
```

And this is how the `records` data are created in the `search_documents`:

```
SELECT GREATEST(MAX(r.privacy), MAX(f.privacy), MAX(a.privacy)) AS privacy,
  'record' AS searchable_type,
  r.id AS searchable_id,
  json_build_object(
    'tags', array_remove(array_agg(t.name), NULL),
    'title', r.title,
    'description', r.description
  ) AS body
FROM records r
  LEFT JOIN folders f ON r.folder_id = f.id
  LEFT JOIN accounts a ON r.account_id = a.id
  LEFT JOIN records_tags rt ON r.id = rt.record_id
  LEFT JOIN tags t ON rt.tag_id = t.id
WHERE r.id = :id
GROUP BY searchable_id
ON CONFLICT(searchable_type, searchable_id)
  DO UPDATE
    SET privacy = EXCLUDED.privacy,
        body = EXCLUDED.body
```

Comment: `"Is there any way how I could use the tag's score in addition to current implementation while calculating the rank?"`  
One solution that I can think of is modifying "rank" as a post-processing step.  
  
After you get rank based on ts_rank of text, then you can modify **rank** using **score** value with your custom formula.

Comment: That's exactly what I ended up with and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 3-argument form of [setweight](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-textsearch.html) to set the weights of specific lexemes, rather setting all weights the same for the entire tsvector.  Presumably you would build this into the creation process of the table "search_documents", but I can't suggest specific implementation since you didn't show us that creation process.  Once you have the properly weighted tsvector, it would probably make sense to store that as a separate column, rather than inside JSONB.

Comment: Actually I did show the ts_vector creation process and I am already using the weights in the setweight function but there are only 4 levels. Anyway, I edited the question and added the data samples as well.

Comment: Unless I am misparsing something, you are using the 2-argument form.  You need to use the 3-argument form.  You didn't show the creation of the search_documents table (materialized view?) itself, which is what is likely needs to be changed to accomodate this.

Comment: As I wrote in the post the search_documents is a table. I added the structure to the question. I tried to make the question as simple as possible without other data because I thought they are not important. Everything is a little bit more complicated since I want to search not just the records but also other tables - accounts and speakers.